# Aligning columns in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

What CSS properties should I set so that the columns will wrap underneath one another, ignoring the height of horizontally-adjacent columns?

[image: Desired layout for wrapping to fit 2 columns across.]

### Unsuccessful attempt

I'm attempting to do this with `display: grid`, but it doesn't behave how I want. An example:

```css
header {
    height: 2.0rem;
    background: PeachPuff;
}
footer {
    height: 2.0rem;
    background: PaleGreen;
}

header,
footer,
section.app-column {
    padding: 1.0rem;
}

section#main section#app-column-primary {
    grid-area: primary;
    height: 5.0rem;
    background: Cyan;
}
section#main section#app-column-secondary {
    grid-area: secondary;
    height: 15.0rem;
    background: Thistle;
}
section#main section#app-column-tertiary {
    grid-area: tertiary;
    height: 10.0rem;
    background: Coral;
}

section#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10.0rem);
    grid-row-gap: 0.2rem;
    grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
}

section#main {
    content: "This application requires a display at least 200 pixels wide.";
}

@media(min-width: 200px) {
    section#main {
        grid-template-areas:
            "primary"
            "secondary"
            "tertiary";
    }
}

@media(min-width: 350px) {
    section#main {
        grid-template-areas:
            "primary secondary"
            "tertiary .";
    }
}

@media(min-width: 520px) {
    section#main {
        grid-template-areas:
            "primary secondary tertiary";
    }
}
```

```html
<header>Header ipsum, dolor sit amet.</header>
<section id="main">
    <section class="app-column" id="app-column-primary">
        Primary app column
    </section>
    <section class="app-column" id="app-column-secondary">
        Secondary app column
    </section>
    <section class="app-column" id="app-column-tertiary">
        Tertiary app column
    </section>
</section>
<footer>Footer ipsum, dolor sit amet.</footer>
```

### Correct result for 3 columns and 1 column

That does what I need for the three-column (`"primary secondary tertiary"`) and one-column (`"primary" "secondary" "tertiary"`) layouts.

[image: Correct layout for 3 columns across.] [image: Correct layout for 1 column across.]

### Unwanted layout for 2 columns

But the two-column layout has the `tertiary` column starting below the `secondary` column:

[image: Incorrect layout for 2 columns across.]

### Desired layout for 2 columns

What I want is for the `tertiary` column placement to ignore the `secondary` column because they won't overlap at all:

[image: Desired layout for wrapping to fit 2 columns across.]

How can I do this with CSS? Is `display: grid` appropriate for this? Should I be using `display: flex` or something different (if so, exactly what CSS properties do I need)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
@media(min-width: 350px) {
    section#main {
        grid-template-areas:
            "primary secondary"
            "tertiary .";
    }
}
```

... which creates a 2x2 grid, like this:

```
[ primary ] [ secondary ]

[tertiary ] [ empty space ]
```

... and is exactly what you're showing as the problem:

[image]

Do this:

```
@media(min-width: 350px) {
    section#main {
        grid-template-areas:
            "primary secondary"
            "tertiary secondary";
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5jeknmqw/)

```css
header {
  height: 2.0rem;
  background: PeachPuff;
}

footer {
  height: 2.0rem;
  background: PaleGreen;
}

header,
footer,
section.app-column {
  padding: 1.0rem;
}

section#main section#app-column-primary {
  grid-area: primary;
  height: 5.0rem;
  background: Cyan;
}

section#main section#app-column-secondary {
  grid-area: secondary;
  height: 15.0rem;
  background: Thistle;
}

section#main section#app-column-tertiary {
  grid-area: tertiary;
  height: 10.0rem;
  background: Coral;
}

section#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10.0rem);
  grid-row-gap: 0.2rem;
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
}

section#main {
  content: "This application requires a display at least 200 pixels wide.";
}

@media(min-width: 200px) {
  section#main {
    grid-template-areas: "primary" "secondary" "tertiary";
  }
}

@media(min-width: 350px) {
  section#main {
    grid-template-areas: "primary secondary" "tertiary secondary";
  }
}

@media(min-width: 520px) {
  section#main {
    grid-template-areas: "primary secondary tertiary";
  }
}
```

```html
<header>Header ipsum, dolor sit amet.</header>
<section id="main">
  <section class="app-column" id="app-column-primary">
    Primary app column
  </section>
  <section class="app-column" id="app-column-secondary">
    Secondary app column
  </section>
  <section class="app-column" id="app-column-tertiary">
    Tertiary app column
  </section>
</section>
<footer>Footer ipsum, dolor sit amet.</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to give you a solution using the property `grid-row-end` and `auto-fill`.

Firstable: this solution works well with your dimentions (it is not very scalable, but unfortunatly, without using javascript, there isn't a perfect and pure CSS solution I think).

BTW, this is how it works:

- I create a grid with `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 10rem);` property
- For every grid items I put a `grid-row-end: span [dimension];`=> for 5rem I put [1], for 15rem I put [3] and for 10 rem I put [2] (this is when I said "*it is not scalable*" 'cause if you change the dimentions you have to change here too)

For all these property you can find very usefull information here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and here: https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/01/18/css-grid-one-layout-method-not-the-only-layout-method/ (I mentioned my CSS guru, I'm a bit excited (^_^;))

This is the code in action:

```css
header {
    height: 2.0rem;
    background: PeachPuff;
}
footer {
    height: 2.0rem;
    background: PaleGreen;
}

header,
footer,
section.app-column {
    padding: 1rem;
}

section#main section#app-column-primary {
    height: 5rem;
    grid-row-end: span 1;
    background: Cyan;
}
section#main section#app-column-secondary {
    grid-row-end: span 3;
    height: 15rem;
    background: Thistle;
}
section#main section#app-column-tertiary {
    grid-row-end: span 2;
    height: 10rem;
    background: Coral;
}

section#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 10rem);
    grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
    grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<header>Header ipsum, dolor sit amet.</header>
<section id="main">
    <section class="app-column" id="app-column-primary">
        Primary app column
    </section>
    <section class="app-column" id="app-column-secondary">
        Secondary app column
    </section>
    <section class="app-column" id="app-column-tertiary">
        Tertiary app column
    </section>
</section>
<footer>Footer ipsum, dolor sit amet.</footer>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.

PS: See also the property `grid-auto-flow: dense;`, in a real world, with some limitations, it can help you to fit the various elements together (I removed it to my example 'cause here we have only 3 elements => the Rachel Andrew articole is very useful for you, I think)